# Demand doesn't throw exception while the try to write to a file throws UnauthorizedAccessException

Tags: c#, .net, security, code-access-security

The code below works fine when Visual Studio is running under Admin account.
But when VS is running under non-priveleged account, Save() method throws UnauthorizedAccessException, but in this case I quite don't understand why Demand() doesn't throw SecurityException.

```
public void SetLoggingLevel(string loggerRuleName, LoggingLevel loggingLevel)
    {           
        foreach (XElement loggerRule in GetLoggerElements().Where(loggerRule => CompareWithLoggerRule(loggerRuleName, loggerRule)))
        {
            loggerRule.SetAttributeValue("minlevel", loggingLevel.ToString());

            var permission = new FileIOPermission(FileIOPermissionAccess.Write, Source);
            permission.Demand();

            _configFile.Save(Source); //Writing to the xml-file
            return;
        }
        throw new RuleNotFoundException("The rule not found.");
    }
```

Comment: did you try using permission.Assert() ?

Comment: Tried. The same result: UnauthorizedAccessException

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FileIOPermission checks code permissions under the .NET Code Access Security model, not user permissions in the Windows file system.  Since your code runs under an admin account, the code presumably has adequate FileIOPermission, so it is unsurprising that the demand passes when running under a different user account.

Since the demand for FileIOPermission does pass, the code attempts to save the file, which is when it runs into insufficient user permissions in the non-admin scenario.  [UnauthorizedAccessException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.unauthorizedaccessexception.aspx) is the expected exception type when the operating system denies access to the target resource.